# Emulator isn't launching

Tags: android, emulation

the emulator i created is a x86 machine 780MB Ram android 4.0.3. I'm working on windows 10. I tried to run the emulator from terminal and it gave me this:  emulator critical updatelayeredwindowindirect failed for ptsd. 
any of you got a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A probable workaround was posted saying: Change the AVD configuration --> Emulated Performance --> Graphics: Software

You can refer to this link for the source:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/286600/cant-start-android-emulator-on-hyper-v.html